# How to create an Android Google MapView without SDK level 11?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create a MapView on SDK version 10, but all the examples of how to create a MapView uses [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html), which is only in API 11.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_a_map_to_an_android_application

I don't want to add an additional support library.

I was able to get the app to load, but the map displays as an empty grey grid. These show up in the log file as the only semi-relevant lines:

```
03-08 23:20:25.088: W/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 23
03-08 23:20:25.088: D/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
03-08 23:20:25.088: D/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
03-08 23:20:25.213: D/dalvikvm(32615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1276K, 48% free 3765K/7175K, external 9476K/10157K, paused 5ms+8ms
03-08 23:20:25.236: I/dalvikvm(32615): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/p/s; (427)
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Link of class 'Lmaps/p/s;' failed
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/y/bo; (3820)
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Link of class 'Lmaps/y/bo;' failed
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Unable to resolve superclass of Lmaps/i/k; (4208)
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): Link of class 'Lmaps/i/k;' failed
03-08 23:20:25.541: E/dalvikvm(32615): Could not find class 'maps.i.k', referenced from method maps.z.ag.a
03-08 23:20:25.541: W/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 3540 (Lmaps/i/k;) in Lmaps/z/ag;
03-08 23:20:25.541: D/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x006d
03-08 23:20:25.627: D/dalvikvm(32615): VFY: dead code 0x006f-007f in Lmaps/z/ag;.a (Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;ZLjava/lang/String;)Lmaps/z/ag;
03-08 23:20:26.275: D/MPAY(32615): map = com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap@40718398
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't want to use Fragments  for MapView ?

Comment: Correct, as it's not supported for API-10, and many phone don't have Honeycomb. There is still [MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview), but they don't give instructions!

Comment: You can check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how. It was a bunch of little things, including I had to implement onResume(), onPause(), etc... I thought I could just get away with calling mapView.onCreate() for testing, but I guess that wasn't enough.

I also found a sample in the Google Play library `...\Java\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\RawMapViewDemoActivity.java`

The example extends FragmentActivity, but that isn't necessary, nor is importing android.support.v4.*.

```
public class RawMapViewDemoActivity extends Activity {
    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();

    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();


    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();


    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();


    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Fragments are supported from the API 11 or above and Maps are now encapsulated in the `MapFragment` class, an extension of Android's `Fragment` class. Now you can add a map as a piece of a larger Activity. With a `MapFragment` object, you can show a map by itself on smaller screens, such as mobile phones, or as a part of a more complex UI on larger-screen devices, such as tablets. So google has also provided the supporting library to implement it in the API 11 or below.

You can use the `android-support-v4.jar` library in your application and implement the GoogleMap as below:

To add the supporting library in your project `Goto->android SDK->extras->android->support->v4->android-support-v4.jar`. Just copy this jar file and add into your application's libs folder and then add to build path. After that you can use the Fragment to add the GoogleMap.

Here i am going to show you how we can implement the GoogleMap in API 10 or below:

First we need to use the supporting library Fragment for the GoogleMap so instead of `MapFragment` we will use `SupportMapFragment` in layout file.

> ```
>    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:id="@+id/map"
>               android:layout_width="match_parent"
>               android:layout_height="match_parent"
>              class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
> ```

In your java file access the map as below:

> ```
> public class MapActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
>
>        private GoogleMap mMap;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>        setContentView(R.layout.main);
>             // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
>          mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
>                 .getMap();
>     }
>    }
> ```

Comment: That's some good info, but I found out how. See my other answer. I didn't want to go through the trouble of adding yet another library, bloating the app, and causing even more confusion among the other developers. Why does Google make things so hard for something so easy? They are going to lose out to things like [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is that you (probably) can't.

The [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) overview says this:

> - Maps are now encapsulated in the MapFragment class, an extension of Android's Fragment class. Now you can add a map as a piece of a larger
>     Activity. With a MapFragment object, you can show a map by itself on
>     smaller screens, such as mobile phones, or as a part of a more complex
>     UI on larger-screen devices, such as tablets.
> - Because maps are encapsulated in the MapFragment class, you can implement them by extending the Android standard Activity class,
>     rather than extending the MapActivity used in version 1.

While it is not stated explicitly, I read that as implying that Maps in v2 are fundamentally dependent on Fragment.

If you need to use SDK 10 or older, and you can't use some kind of backport of `Fragment`, then you probably can't use the Google Maps API v2.

Comment: They still have [MapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview) class, but they don't give any instruction on using it!

Answer (score 0):

And at present to support in all versions, without library you cant use it.Specially Jake

wharton's sherlock library https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock  provides you to

support in all versions. You can use mapview balloons for MapView and android sherlock mapview

jar file has been provided.You can use that.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/